# StreamAPI Collectors.groupingBy empty collection instead of null

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
List<Entity> entities = ...
Map<Boolean, List<Entity>> entitiesByIsTest = entities.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entity::isTest));
```

It is obvious, that the result map has the only keys which is present in grouping property. It must work like this for types with infinitive set of values. But what about enums/booleans/other determined types?

Is it possible to implement initialization of empty collections more elegantly than in snippet below?

```
if (entitiesByIsTest.get(true) == null) {
    entitiesByIsTest.put(true, new ArrayList());
}
```

Comment: hard to understand the question. what it the purpose of your code?

Comment: The purpose is divide set to two independent sets then do some different actions - for example persist regular entities, but save just count of test entities

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If you want `Boolean` keys and both mappings always initialized, use [`partitioningBy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-), which has exactly the desired properties.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Entity>> entitiesByIsTest = entities.stream()
                        .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(Entity::isTest));
```

If the key is an `enum`, you have to stay with `groupingBy`, but you may replace the subsequent `get` operations with

```
List<Entity> value=map.computeIfAbsent(key, x->new ArrayList<>());
```

which will construct and put a new `ArrayList` if and only if there was no previous mapping and return the actual mapped value in either case (unlike `putIfAbsent`).

Of course, you could add all absent values in one eager operation instead:

```
EnumSet.allOf(KeyType.class).forEach(key->map.computeIfAbsent(key, x->new ArrayList<>()));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use `entitiesByIsTest.putIfAbsent(true,new ArrayList());` that should add a new empty arraylist only when there is nothing in the map for that key

Comment: thanks! good point. One thing is that this is not a functional style. My main purpose is to use all the advantages of stream api such as clear code, avoiding states as much as possible

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're asking for.  You already have a solution for the `groupingBy` thing -- that _already_ works for enums, booleans, or whatever types.  This answer answers your second question, how to initialize empty collections in the map.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own collector.

```
Collectors.of(
   //**Initialize map with all of your values**//,
   entity -> map.get(entity.isTest()).add(entity),
   (left, right) -> right.forEach(r -> left.get(r.getKey()).addAll(r.getValue)); return r;)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass in a supplier of a map already containing empty lists as values for all expected keys.

This should group by enum elements:

```
Map<Type, List<Value>> emptyMap = EnumSet.allOf(Type.class)
                .stream()
                .collect(toMap(identity(), f -> new ArrayList<>()));
Function<Value, Type> fun = this::groupByType;
Map<Type, List<Value>> groups = values.stream()
                .collect(groupingBy(fun, () -> emptyMap, toList()));
```